# converting year-month-day to julian day

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, julian-date

i have a list that contain data in the format(year-month-day-hrmn-00S.GHTUJ_035)

```
2017-01-22-1522-00S.GHTUJ_035
2016-12-21-1725-00S.GHTUJ_035
2019-11-25-1123-00S.GHTUJ_035
2015-09-25-1329-00S.GHTUJ_035
```

Now i want to convert `year-month-day` portion of the data to julianday and want to paste it in its right side. so my expected output should be

```
2017-01-22-1522-00S.GHTUJ_035   022
2016-12-21-1725-00S.GHTUJ_035   ...
2019-11-25-1123-00S.GHTUJ_035   329
2015-09-25-1329-00S.GHTUJ_035   ...
```

i am able to write only half part of the script so i need experts help.Thanks in advance.

```
while read line;
do
echo $line
done< list
```

Comment: You have bash in your tags, but can you use other tools? What have you tried so far to interpret the date which didn't work?

Comment: can u please show it to my data

Comment: @tink The link is for getting the *current* Julian day, not how to convert.

Comment: please suggest a solution sir...

Comment: Are you interested in the [Julian Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day), or the Day of year?

Comment: i am interested in julian day

Comment: @cigien - that's what the title says ... but the first function does a generic conversion.

Answer (score 1):

`datepart=${line%-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-00S*}` will give you the date part of your string and you can use `date +%j -d $datepart` to convert it to julian.

`${line%-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-00S*}` is `bash` syntax for take `$line` and remove everything (that is what `%` means) from `-`, four digits, another `-` and `00S` up to the end of the string (the `*`).

`date -d` allows you to give a specific date to perform the actions on. The `+%j` tells date what output it should give. See `man dae` for details and more options.

Comment: This is not julian day, but day of year

Comment: In computer programming, the meaning of Julian date changes sometimes. Julian date is considered to be the number of elapsed days since the beginning of a particular year. Which matches by the way exactly the OP's required output. It is not a coincidence that date uses the letter `j` for this format.

Comment: Okay, I had no clue! Upvote for learning something here